Using pac4j token request for login.gov fails because client_assertion includes null iat claim
I am trying to use pac4j oidc-client to authenticate with login.gov with this security configuration:
oidcConfiguration.setDiscoveryURI("https://idp.int.identitysandbox.gov/.well-known/openid-configuration");
oidcConfiguration.setClientId(clientId);
oidcConfiguration.setUseNonce(true);
oidcConfiguration.setResponseType("code");
oidcConfiguration.setScope("openid");
// Load private key from PEM file
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File pkFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("private.pem").getFile());
var privateKey = readPKCS8PrivateKey(pkFile);
var privateKeyJwtConfig = new PrivateKeyJWTClientAuthnMethodConfig(JWSAlgorithm.RS256, privateKey);
oidcConfiguration.setPrivateKeyJWTClientAuthnMethodConfig(privateKeyJwtConfig);
oidcConfiguration.addCustomParam("acr_values", "http://idmanagement.gov/ns/assurance/ial/1");
oidcConfiguration.addCustomParam("prompt", "select_account");
oidcConfiguration.addCustomParam("client_assertion_type","urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer");
oidcConfiguration.setClientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.PRIVATE_KEY_JWT);
oidcConfiguration.setStateGenerator(new RandomValueGenerator(28));
oidcConfiguration.setWithState(true);
oidcConfiguration.setPreferredJwsAlgorithm(JWSAlgorithm.RS256);
oidcConfiguration.setSecret("bogus");

NB: Setting a secret was necessary for the request sent to the token endpoint to include a client_assertion, even though no secret has been set in the login.gov configuration.
The payload of the client_assertion sent by pac4j includes a null iat claim and the token endpoint responds with an error, and an exception is thrown:
JEE PAC4J DEMO 17:53:54.491 [qtp1990828041-45] DEBUG o.p.core.engine.DefaultCallbackLogic - extracted credentials: OidcCredentials(code=e45f8b5b-d039-4c0d-9c75-f6251568fb80, accessToken=null, refreshToken=null, idToken=null)
[WARNING] /callback
org.pac4j.oidc.exceptions.OidcTokenException: Bad token response, error=Client assertion iat must be an integer or floating point Unix timestamp representing a time in the past, description=null, status=400
    at org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator.executeTokenRequest(OidcAuthenticator.java:120)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator.validate(OidcAuthenticator.java:65)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.internalValidateCredentials(BaseClient.java:113)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.validateCredentials(BaseClient.java:95)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultCallbackLogic.perform(DefaultCallbackLogic.java:83)
    at org.pac4j.jee.filter.CallbackFilter.internalFilter(CallbackFilter.java:63)
    at org.pac4j.jee.config.AbstractConfigFilter.doFilter(AbstractConfigFilter.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:170)


The payload of the client_assertion sent by pac4j includes an iat claim that is null.
{
  "sub": "urn:gov:gsa:openidconnect.profiles:sp:sso:doi:quicktime_9996",
  "aud": "https://idp.int.identitysandbox.gov/api/openid_connect/token",
  "nbf": null,
  "iss": "urn:gov:gsa:openidconnect.profiles:sp:sso:doi:quicktime_9996",
  "exp": 1717804013,
  "iat": null,
  "jti": "mspXEErL5LUDuO-x5IUmTYDB679lA0TyYPYIT6d2_xg"
}

What would be the way to make the iat claim generated by pac4j be the current system timestamp instead of a null?

What version of pac4j do you use?

Per the pom.xml:
<properties> <pac4jVersion>6.0.3</pac4jVersion> <jee-pac4j.version>8.0.1</jee-pac4j.version> <java.version>17</java.version> <spring.version>6.1.8</spring.version> </properties> 

I can confirm that the iat claim is not generated, but it is optional, isn't it? The client authentication method is computed in the OidcOpMetadataResolver via the PrivateKeyJWT object. You should define your own opMetadataResolver in the OidcConfiguration.

The Login.gov token endpoint requires 5 claims in the client_assertion: iss, sub, aud, jti, and exp. As suggested, I created a subclass of OidcOpMetadataResolver overriding the computeClientAuthentication method and created a PrivateKeyJWT with the claims required by Login.gov.
